# Angular 2 Router - routing for start page of an application

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

I just upgraded Angular2 to final version and I am looking for nice way of doing following.

I have a start page that shows a group of users at the start, this group is known by accessing a REST service.

I go www.app.com - angular app starts, it retrieves which group it should display. At this moment I would like application to go to www.app.com/group/group1 - but before group name is retrieved angular already tries to navigate and throws an exception because it didn't find route.

I come up with 2 hacks:

- make '' route go to GroupSelector component, and from there navigate after group name gets resolved, it is bad as I really want to start my app on another component
- wait for group name and then navigate with Router.navigate, this throws exception because route wasn't found, even though app works

With previous version of Angular2 Router (beta 1), I started the application like www.app.com - app got loaded, it retrieved name of a group and then by using Router.navigate application would load Groups component and provided correct group name parameter to this component, and everything worked just fine

Is there any way how to delay router, and redirect to proper route only after necessary data are retrieved from REST service?

Comment: In the subscribe to the HTTP get return, execute a this.router.navigate['myRoute'];

Answer (score 2):

Use resolve attribute in router config file

```
// team.resolve.ts
@Injectable()
class TeamResolver implements Resolve<{}> {
  constructor(private http: Http) {}
  resolve(
    route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot,
    state: RouterStateSnapshot
  ): Observable<any>|Promise<any>|any {
    return this.http.get("/api/team/" + route.params.id);
  }
}

// app.module.ts
@NgModule({
  imports: [
    RouterModule.forRoot([
      {
        path: 'team/:id',
        component: TeamCmp,
        resolve: {
          team: TeamResolver
        }
      }
    ])
  ],
  providers: [TeamResolver]
})
class AppModule {}
```

https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/router/index/Resolve-interface.html